# How do I change the default font-family for all slides in keynote

Tags: keynote

I am using  keynote 2009 and I want all my slides to have the font-family "Courier". I tried playing with master slides but when I create a new slide it defaults to "Gill Sans".

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: NOTICE: The best answer is by @Haru, currently not accepted nor the highest upvoted, but is far and away the fastest and easiest and most correct answer to this question.

Answer (score 15):

You can change the [`Master Slide`](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH26013?locale=en_US&viewlocale=en_US) to get the fonts you want, and if you’d like this to be the default, then you can save this out as a [`Theme`](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH16967?locale=en_US&viewlocale=en_US).

(Caveat: I only have iWork ’11 in front of me, but I believe it's the same, for iWork ’09).

#### (i) Adjust font for a *single* presentation

1. Open the complete set of `Master Slides`. `View` > `Show/Edit Master Slides`.
2. Find the `Master Slide(s)` that corresponds to slides that you’ve used in your presentation. Open the Fonts panel (`Format` > `Font` > `Show Fonts`, or the `Fonts` item in the toolbar).
3. Select everything in the slide (`Edit` > `Select All`, or `⌘A`), and then, in the fonts panel, select `Courier` instead of `Gill Sans`.
4. Repeat for every `Master Slide` you need.
5. Create a text box and format it with the font/style you want. Then select it and choose `Format` > `Advanced` > `Define Text for All Masters`.

#### (ii) Adjust font of a theme for all future presentations based on this theme

Create a blank slide show with the chosen `Theme`, make these edits on every `Master Slide`. (Every slide should now have `Courier` instead of `Gill Sans` as the default font).

Then save this out as a new `Theme` (`File` > `Save theme…`) to avoid overwriting the default. Call it something descriptive, like `Courier Black`, and just save it.

Now, next time the `Theme` chooser pops up, you’ll be able to choose your `Courier Black` variant, which will have `Courier` as the default.

Comment: How do you have iWork 11 if the latest one released is 09?

Comment: @slhck: good question, I have no idea what I thought when I was writing that. :S

Comment: 'Repeat for every master slide you need.' OK, so this answer is 'you have to do it manually'. This is plainly incorrect - see below.

Answer (score 14):

I hope you get to read this - the others were really not the best advice
IT IS **MUCH MUCH** SIMPLER

Select a MASTER text box and change it's font.
*Format > Advanced > Define Text for Current Master* or *Define Text for All Masters*

Comment: What's a master text box and how do you create one?

Comment: "master text box" means any text box on any master slide.

Answer (score 12):

Most answers and tutorials are outdated due to software updates.
Simpler way is to search from Help.

1. Go to "Help" from top-bar
2. Search "Replace Font"
3. Follow procedure

Comment: The fastest way

Comment: this worked quick and simple

Comment: This is the way. Accept this answer @user998!

Answer (score 5):

Apple Anonymous May 2, 2014 12:37 PM in response to Sullivans in Kansas City

I FINALLY FIGURED IT OUT!!!!! Pay it forward, pass this along.

The easiest way to change ALL fonts on EVERY slide of the ENTIRE slide show AT ONCE: (for Keynote)

- "View"
- "Show Document Warnings"
- Click "Description" Box (so all words, symbols, etc. listed become highlighted)
- "Replace Font" tab will become ungreyed
- Click, "Replace Font"
- Select the font you want the slideshow to be replaced with

Voila!

Answer (score 1):

Drag your altered master slide over the new slide with the incorrect font. When you make a new slide, have one whose master slide has the desired font selected.

Answer (score -3):

The best way, ditch Keynote and buy Microsoft office powerpoint.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  How would this function be improved using PPT? An explanation of how easily a total font family switch would be implemented would be useful to document.

Comment: @bmike It would still not be an answer to the question "how to change the default font-family for all slides __in Keynote?__".

Comment: I'm lenient and tolerant to any answer that attempts to answer. If someone says - I know you asked for X - but here is Y is better in my information and then makes a convincing case. We don't even delete entirely wrong answers - they do tend to get down voted, though. This one isn't even wrong - it's just not useful without an edit. Editing things can often make a marginal post super useful - so patience is advised when someone is new here to the ways we run things.