# How do I change the default font for comment boxes in Keynote

Tags: macos, keynote

I am using Keynote '09 and whenever I create a comment, it is formatted in Marker Felt 16. I want to change that to something like Arial 20. How can I do it?

I tried to apply the point 5 in this [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/14341#answer-32682), namely to create a comment in the master, format it and then select it and choose `Format` > `Advanced` > `Define Text for All Masters`. However `Define Text for All Masters` is greyed out for comments boxes.

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This applies to Keynote 09 (5.3):

1. Create a comment on a master page, style as you wish.
2. With the comment selected, choose `Format` > `Advanced` > `Define Comment for
   all Masters`
3. You may now even delete the comment on your master page.
   New comments in the presentation will still be in the chosen format.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks! In fact the trick was, once you've formatted the text, to click _somewhere on the border of the comment_ (outside the text area). There is no feedback that the comment is selected, but the text cursor mustn't blink. Then `Define Comment for all Masters` becomes available in `Format` > `Advanced`. If the text cursor is active, this menu isn't available.

Comment: Thank **you**! I had never even considered you could change that horrible default font.

Comment: I have tried the above procedure. No matter what I do, when I click on Advanced, everything is still gray. Could you please explain the procedure stepwise? I have Keynote 5.3.